# reset uncontrolled component content after submitting the form + react + jsx

Tags: reactjs, reset, jsx

I have a already built React form, which works fine expect reset functionality. It has used uncontrolled components bit different way. I am looking for what I need to follow, change the code to achieve my goal.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
import * as React from "react";
import WidgetComponent from './../../lib/WidgetComponent';
import jQuery from 'jquery';

import InputListComponent from './components/InputListComponent';
import FormInputComponent from './components/FormInputComponent';
import formTextInputComponent from './components/formTextInputComponent';

import FormInputPasswordComponent from './components/FormInputPasswordComponent';
import FormSelectComponent from './components/FormSelectComponent';
import SubmitBtnListComponent from './components/SubmitBtnListComponent';
import SubmitBtnComponent from './components/SubmitBtnComponent';
import ErrorListBox from './components/ErrorListBox';
import EmailPromptModal from './components/EmailPromptModal';

import formHandlerInterfaceFactory from './lib/formHandlerInterface';
import formValidator from './lib/formValidators';
import {generateJQueryAjaxConfigFromPlaceholders} from './../../lib/GenerateJQueryAjaxConfig';

import './styles/registration-form.scss';

export default class ControlPanelCreateAccounts extends WidgetComponent {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            form: {
                firstName: "",
                lastName: "",
                username: "",
                password: "",
                confirmPassword: "",
                email: "",
                phone: "",
                accessLevel: -1,

            },
            userRoles: [],

            validInputs: {
                firstName: false,
                lastName: false,
                username: false,
                password: false,
                confirmPassword: false,
                email: false,
                phone: false,
                accessLevel: false,

            },
            defaultValue: {
                firstName: "",
                lastName: "",
                username: "",
                password: "",
                confirmPassword: "",
                email: "",
                phone: "",
                accessLevel: -1,
            },
            errors: [],
            submitService: null,
            userRoleService: null,
            newUserId: null,
        };

        this.onFormInputChange = this.onFormInputChange.bind(this);
        this.onServicesCalled = this.onServicesCalled.bind(this);
        this.onFormSubmit = this.onFormSubmit.bind(this);
        this.formElementInvalid = this.formElementInvalid.bind(this);
        this.formElementValid = this.formElementValid.bind(this);
        this.postWidgetLoad = this.postWidgetLoad.bind(this);
        this.createUserRequest = this.createUserRequest.bind(this);
        this.createUserRoleRequest = this.createUserRoleRequest.bind(this);
        this.onResetReceived = this.onResetReceived.bind(this);
        this.onFormInputReset = this.onFormInputReset.bind(this);

    }

    onResetReceived(){
        console.log('onResetReceived');
        let newState = Object.assign(this.state.form, {
            firstName : "",
        });

        this.setState(newState);
        console.log(this.state.form);

    }

    postWidgetLoad(widget) {
        EmailPromptModal.service = widget.services[2];//??
        let submitService = widget.services[1];//1
        let userRoleService = widget.services[2];//2
        //this.storeState({ submitService });
        let newState = Object.assign(this.state, {
            submitService: submitService,
            userRoleService: userRoleService
        });

        this.setState(newState);
    }

    validate() {
        console.log('validating pre-submit');
        let errors = Object.keys(this.state.validInputs).reduce((accum, current) => {
            console.log('state of accumulator is: ');
            console.log(accum);
            console.log('current iteration is: ' + current);

            //console.log('password and reType passwords are : ');
            //console.log(this.state.form.password + " :: " + this.state.confirmPassword );

            if (this.state.validInputs[current] === false) {
                console.log('current input is invalid');
                this.validate = this.validate.bind(this);
                if (current === 'firstName') {
                    accum.push('The first name field is either empty or contains invalid characters');
                }

                if (current === 'lastName') {
                    accum.push('The last name field is either empty or contains invalid characters');
                }

                if (current === 'email') {
                    accum.push('The email field is empty or is not a valid email address');
                }

                if (current === 'phone') {
                    accum.push('The phone field is empty or is not a valid phone number');
                }

                if (current === 'password') {
                    accum.push('The password field is empty or contain less than 5 characters or contain invalid character');
                }

                if (current === 'confirmPassword') {
                    accum.push('The passwords mismatched');
                }

                if (current === 'accessLevel') {
                    accum.push('You must select a accessLevel from the drop-down menu.');
                }
            }

            return accum;
        }, []);

        console.log('final error list looks like: ');
        console.log(errors);

        this.storeState({
            errors: errors
        });

        return errors.length === 0;
    }

    onServicesCalled() {
        let response = arguments[0][0].data;
        let roleList = [];

        if (response) {
            response.map(element => {
                roleList.push({val: element.id, text: element.role_name});
            });
        }

        let newState = Object.assign(this.state, {
            userRoles: roleList
        });

        this.setState(newState);
    }

    onFormInputChange(ev, legend) {
        let value = ev.target.value;
        let form = this.state.form;
        form[legend] = value;
        this.storeState({
            form
        });
   

    formElementInvalid(elem) {
        let name = elem.name;
        let stateUpdateObj = this.state.validInputs;
        stateUpdateObj[name] = false;
        this.storeState({validInputs: stateUpdateObj});

        if (name !== 'status') {
            elem.classList.add('input-error');
        } else {
            document.getElementById('status-error-field').classList.add('visible');
        }
    }

    formElementValid(elem) {
        let name = elem.name;
        let stateUpdateObj = this.state.validInputs;
        stateUpdateObj[name] = true;
        this.storeState({validInputs: stateUpdateObj});

        if (name !== 'status') {
            elem.classList.remove('input-error');
        } else {
            document.getElementById('status-error-field').classList.remove('visible');
        }
    }

    onFormSubmit() {

        if (this.validate()) {
            console.log("validate got passed");
            console.log(this.state.form);
            var id;

            // match password fields
            if (this.state.form.password !== this.state.form.confirmPassword) {
                let stateUpdateObj = this.state.validInputs;
                stateUpdateObj['confirmPassword'] = false;
                this.storeState({validInputs: stateUpdateObj});
                this.onFormSubmit();

            } else {
                jQuery.when(this.createUserRequest()).done((r) => {

                    console.log("submit for createUser is success reload!");
                    console.log(r);

                    id = r.data.id;

                    jQuery.when(this.createUserRoleRequest(id)).done((r) => {

                        console.log("submit for createUserRole is success reload!");
                        console.log(r);

                        if(r.data.wasSuccessful){
                            console.log("create UserRole is successful, So reload the table ");
                            // do page refresh here
                            window.pubsub.publish('isp.reload-control-users', {});

                            //reset the form
                            console.log("reset the form contents");
                            this.onResetReceived();


                        }

                    }).fail((xhr, status, error) => {
                        console.log(status);
                        console.error(error);
                        alert('An error occured while submitting this request, if this issue persists please contact support.');
                    });

                    let newState = Object.assign(this.state, {
                        newUserId: r.data.id
                    });

                    this.setState(newState);


                }).fail((xhr, status, error) => {
                    console.log(status);
                    console.error(error);
                    alert('An error occured while submitting this request, if this issue persists please contact support.');
                });


            }

        }
    }

    //create a record in is_auth_roles table
    createUserRoleRequest(id) {

        let config = generateJQueryAjaxConfigFromPlaceholders(this.state.userRoleService, {'userId': id});

        config.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json';
        config.headers['Accept'] = '*/*';
        config.data = JSON.stringify({
            'roleId': this.state.form.accessLevel,
            'type': 'add'
        });
        console.log("submit config of createUserRoleRequest() is: ");
        console.log(config);

        return jQuery.ajax(config);

    }

    createUserRequest() {
        let config = generateJQueryAjaxConfigFromPlaceholders(this.state.submitService, {});

        config.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json';
        config.headers['Accept'] = '*/*';
        config.data = JSON.stringify({
            firstName: this.state.form.firstName,
            lastName: this.state.form.lastName,
            username: this.state.form.username,
            phone: this.state.form.phone,
            password: this.state.form.password,
            confirmPassword: this.state.form.confirmPassword,
            email: this.state.form.email,
            accessLevel: this.state.accessLevel

        });

        console.log("submit config is: ");
        console.log(config);

        return jQuery.ajax(config);
    }

    render() {
            return (

            <div className="registration-form">
                <h3 className="component-title"><i className="fa fa-table" aria-hidden="true"></i> User <span> Registration</span></h3><br/>
                <InputListComponent>
                                        {/*onValid={this.formElementValid} />*/}
                    <formTextInputComponent legend="firstName" label="First Name" placeholder="First Name" onChange={this.onFormInputChange} validator={formValidator.nameValidator} onInvalid={this.formElementInvalid} default = {this.state.defaultValue.firstName} value={ this.state.value}
                                        onValid={this.formElementValid} />

                    <FormInputComponent legend="lastName" label="Last Name" placeholder="Last Name" onChange={this.onFormInputChange} validator={formValidator.nameValidator} onInvalid={this.formElementInvalid} default = {this.state.defaultValue.lastName}
                                        onValid={this.formElementValid}/>
                    <FormInputComponent legend="username" label="User Name" placeholder="User Name" onChange={this.onFormInputChange} validator={formValidator.nameValidator} onInvalid={this.formElementInvalid} default = {this.state.defaultValue.username}
                                        onValid={this.formElementValid}/>
                    <FormInputPasswordComponent legend="password" label="Password" placeholder="Password" onChange={this.onFormInputChange} validator={formValidator.passwordValidator} onInvalid={this.formElementInvalid} default = {this.state.defaultValue.password}
                                                onValid={this.formElementValid}/>
                    <FormInputPasswordComponent legend="confirmPassword" label="Confirm Password" placeholder="Confirm Password" onChange={this.onFormInputChange} validator={formValidator.passwordValidator} default = {this.state.defaultValue.confirmPassword}
                                                onInvalid={this.formElementInvalid} onValid={this.formElementValid}/>
                    <FormInputComponent legend="email" label="Email Address" placeholder="Email" onChange={this.onFormInputChange} validator={formValidator.emailValidator} onInvalid={this.formElementInvalid} default = {this.state.defaultValue.email}
                                        onValid={this.formElementValid}/>
                    <FormInputComponent legend="phone" label="Phone Number" placeholder="Phone Number" onChange={this.onFormInputChange} validator={formValidator.phoneValidator} onInvalid={this.formElementInvalid} default = {this.state.defaultValue.phone}
                                        onValid={this.formElementValid}/>
                    <FormSelectComponent legend="accessLevel" data={this.state.userRoles} onChange={this.onFormInputChange} validator={formValidator.statusValidator} onInvalid={this.formElementInvalid} default = {this.state.defaultValue.accessLevel}
                                         onValid={this.formElementValid}/>
                </InputListComponent>


                <ErrorListBox errorList={this.state.errors}/>
                <button className="dataTable-modal-btn click-btn" onClick={this.onFormSubmit}>CREATE USER</button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
window.ControlPanelCreateAccounts = ControlPanelCreateAccounts;
window.CurrentWidget = window.ControlPanelCreateAccounts;
```

this is formInputComponent code

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
const FormInputComponent = (props) => {

    const onChangeHandler = (ev) => {
        if(props.validator(ev.target.value)) {
            props.onChange(ev, props.legend);
            props.onValid(ev.target);
        } else {
            props.onInvalid(ev.target);
        }
    };

    console.log('props.defaultValue');
    console.log(props.legend);
    console.log(props.default);
    console.log(props.value);
    return (
        <div className="form-row">
            <label>{props.label}</label><br />
            <input name={props.legend} type="text" placeholder={props.placeholder} onChange={onChangeHandler} defaultValue={props.default || ''} value={props.value}/>
        </div>
    );
};

FormInputComponent.propTypes = {
    legend: React.PropTypes.string,
    label: React.PropTypes.string,
    placeholder: React.PropTypes.string,
    onChange: React.PropTypes.func,
    validator: React.PropTypes.func,
    onInvalid: React.PropTypes.func,
    onValid: React.PropTypes.func,
    default: React.PropTypes.string,
};

export default FormInputComponent;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want `setState` inside of `onResetReceived` to reset the form, you'll need to set the `value` prop of each form field. The `default` prop gets sent to `FormInputComponent` as the `defaultValue` of the `input`, but you can also see it accepts a `value={props.value}` as well (even though `value` is not defined in its `PropTypes`. From the parent set

```
<FormInputComponent value={this.state.form.firstName} ... />
```

This will ensure changing `this.state.form` via `setState` will update each form field.

Comment: adding <FormInputComponent value={this.state.form.firstName} ... /> makes input field issue. it replace the typing characters by value of `states` every time. it simply cant type any value.

Comment: When you call `this.storeState` do you mean to be calling `this.setState`? https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#setstate